# C# Syntax - Example of a Lambda Expression - ForEach() over Generic List

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, lambda

First, I know there are methods off of the generic `List<>` class already in the framework do iterate over the `List<>`.

But as an example, what is the correct syntax to write a ForEach method to iterate over each object of a `List<>`, and do a `Console.WriteLine(object.ToString())` on each object.
Something that takes the `List<>` as the first argument and the lambda expression as the second argument.

Most of the examples I have seen are done as extension methods or involve LINQ. I'm looking for a plain-old method example.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
public void Each<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
        action(item);
}
```

... and call it thusly:

```
Each(myList, i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

Comment: Cool. Now where does the Func<> syntax that I have seen around come into play?

Comment: Func<> delegates are generic delegates for methods with return values.   Action<> delegates are generic delegates for methods WITHOUT return values.  Thats the only difference.

Comment: so in your case, you don't need to return something (from console.writeline - so Action<T> is sufficient.

Comment: Also, you can just use the methodgroup "Console.WriteLine" instead of the lambda "i => Console.WriteLine(i)"

Answer (score 57):

Is this what you're asking for?

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
numbers.ToList().ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine(n));
```

Comment: yes. this handy and I have used it. +1. At the time I asked the question I think I was just trying to get a handle on basic C# lambda syntax when used with generics.

Comment: Ok, but we have to consider that ToList() is an O(n) operation

Answer (score 42):

The above could also be written with less code as:

```
new List<SomeType>(items).ForEach(
    i => Console.WriteLine(i)
);
```

This creates a generic list and populates it with the IEnumerable and then calls the list objects ForEach.

Comment: The question asked how to write the method (not how to call it), and specified that he did not want to use LINQ or Extension methods.

Comment: This is convenient, but isn't the overhead of creating a new list (implying iterating over the items at least one additional time) usually not worth it?

Answer (score 15):

```
public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action) {
foreach (var item in items) {
    action(item);
} }
```

... and call it thusly:

```
myList.Each(x => { x.Enabled = false; });
```

Comment: A plus for showing the way to do multiple operation in Each.

Answer (score 4):

Want to put out there that there is not much to worry about if someone provides an answer as an extension method because an extension method is just a cool way to call an instance method. I understand that you want the answer without using an extension method. Regardless if the method is defined as static, instance or extension - the result is the same.

The code below uses the code from the accepted answer to define an extension method and an instance method and creates a unit test to show the output is the same.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ForEachTests
{
    public void Each<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }

    private string _extensionOutput;

    private void SaveExtensionOutput(string value)
    {
        _extensionOutput += value;
    }

    private string _instanceOutput;

    private void SaveInstanceOutput(string value)
    {
        _instanceOutput += value;
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        string[] teams = new string[] {"cowboys", "falcons", "browns", "chargers", "rams", "seahawks", "lions", "heat", "blackhawks", "penguins", "pirates"};

        Each(teams, SaveInstanceOutput);

        teams.Each(SaveExtensionOutput);

        Assert.AreEqual(_extensionOutput, _instanceOutput);
    }
}
```

Quite literally, the only thing you need to do to convert an extension method to an instance method is remove the `static` modifier and the first parameter of the method.

This method

```
public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        action(item);
    }
 }
```

becomes

```
public void Each<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        action(item);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse each string in the list and even you can search in the whole generic using a single statement this makes searching easier.

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
List names = new List();

names.Add(“Saurabh”);
names.Add("Garima");
names.Add(“Vivek”);
names.Add(“Sandeep”);

string stringResult = names.Find( name => name.Equals(“Garima”));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard:

```
foreach (Item i in allItems)
{
   i.FK_ItemStatus_CustomCodeID = itemStatuses.Where(
      x => x.CustomCodeID == i.ItemStatus_CustomCodeID).FirstOrDefault();                        
}
```

Lambda:

```
allItems.ForEach(
   i => i.FK_ItemStatus_CustomCodeID = 
      itemStatuses.Where(
         x => x.CustomCodeID == i.ItemStatus_CustomCodeID).FirstOrDefault()
      );
```