# ASP.NET MVC/C# - Type casting to an array in a custom required validation attribute

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, custom-attributes

I'm attempting to create a custom required validation attribute which will be able to take in a 1d array of any size and verify that at least one element is not null/empty string.  I'm having some trouble figuring out how to turn the incoming generic object into an array.  Here's what I have so far:

```
public class RequiredArrayAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var valueType = value.GetType();

        if (!valueType.IsArray)
        {
            return false;
        }

        bool hasValue = false;

        foreach (var item in value)
        {
            /* if (item != null/empty)
             * {
             *    hasValue = true;
             * }
            */
        }

        return hasValue;
    }
}
```

While my specific use case in this instance will be dealing with `string[]`, I'd like to keep the attribute as generic as possible for future use in other projects.  Any ideas on how to proceed?

EDIT:

I basically need to do something like:

```
foreach (var item in (valueType[])value)
{
    // ...
}
```

But I'm not sure how/if it's possible to dynamically cast to an array like that.

Comment: What version of C# are you using?  Can you use Linq and generics? ie. if you had a generic collection you could do something like .Where(x => x != null).Count() > 0 - of course that handles the null part rather than the empty string part :)

Comment: I'm using C# 4, so I have both LINQ and generics.  I can represent my model data as a List<string> without a problem.  However, the main problem still remains - how would I cast object value as a List<T>?

Comment: Does this help - something like the below - Assuming the object implements IList as opposed to IEnumerable: 
IList collection = (IList)myObject;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe you need following:
generic handeling of your loop: check answer below

[C# Syntax - Example of a Lambda Expression - ForEach() over Generic List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339199/c-syntax-example-of-a-lambda-expression-foreach-over-generic-list)

Cast as T:

you can create separate class that will represent T

eg:
public class Foo{
public string Boo{get;set;}
}

and after you put it into List list = new List() etc:)

Comment: See my comment to Jen on my question.