# Change foreach loop to lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Syntax - Example of a Lambda Expression - ForEach() over Generic List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339199/c-sharp-syntax-example-of-a-lambda-expression-foreach-over-generic-list)

I would like to simplify my code and change it to something shorter and still readable code.

```
List<string> onlineModelsNumbers = new List<string>();

foreach (OnlineModel om in OnlineModels)
    onlineModelsNumbers.Add(om.model_id.ToString());
```

Here I'm thinking about writing the same thing in a lambda expression. But how do I do that?

```
List<string> onlineModelsNumbersL = onlineModelsNumbers.ForEach(...)
```

or

```
List<string> onlineModelsNumbersL = new List<string>(onlineModelsNumbers.ForEach(...))
```

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<string> onlineModelsNumbers = OnlineModels.Select(om => om.model_id.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: You will need to call ToList() if you want a List<string>.

Comment: Just saw that as you posted. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
onlineModelsNumbers.AddRange(OnlineModels.Select(o => o.model_id.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var onlineModelsNumbers = OnlineModels.Select(m => m.model_id.ToString())
                                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ [purposely does not come with a `ForEach` extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) (so that LINQ functions remain pure) but it is easy to write your own that wraps a `foreach`.

Comment: It does come with a ForEach extension for Lists....

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already simple. You could consider using an implicitly-typed loop variable:

```
foreach(var om in OnlineModels)
{
    onlineModelNumbers.Add(om.model_id.ToString());
}
```

Or you could use `AddRange`:

```
onlineModelNumbers.AddRange(OnlineModels.Select(om => om.model_id.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a foreach here, select will do that for you:

```
IEnumerable<string> = OnlineModels.Select(x => x.model_id.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just transform and add it as a range:

```
List<string> onlineModelsNumbers = new List<string>(OnlineModels.Select(om => om.model_id.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to perform your  "foreach" on every member of OnlineModels, and as a result want to add the model's model_id string representation to onlineModelsNumbers.

I'd expect to write the expressions as follows:

```
onlineModels.ForEach(om => onlineModelsNumbers.Add(om.model_id.ToString()))
```

Comment: This is rather poor practice as you're causing, and also relying on, the side effects of a functional style call.  It would be preferable to use either `AddRange` or `ToList` to avoid that.